# Magento 2 : How to get Shipping Methods for Specific Customer Group

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, customer-group

How can I get list of shipping methods for the different customer group.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Create a system configuration under each shipping method called Customer Group
2. Create a plugin for each of the shipping methods collectRates, check the customer group logic

Answer (score 0):

[In brief please check this link](https://php-scripts-form.blogspot.com/2023/06/magento-2-how-to-get-shipping-methods.html)

**1. Inject the necessary dependencies in your class constructor or method. You will need the following dependencies:**

```
    use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Quote\Api\ShippingMethodManagementInterface;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateCollectorInterface;
```

**2. Create class properties for the injected dependencies:**

```
    protected $groupRepository;
    protected $shippingMethodManagement;
    protected $rateCollector;
```

**3. Initialize the dependencies in the constructor:**

```
    public function __construct(
        GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
        ShippingMethodManagementInterface $shippingMethodManagement,
        RateCollectorInterface $rateCollector
    ) {
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
        $this->shippingMethodManagement = $shippingMethodManagement;
        $this->rateCollector = $rateCollector;
    }
```

**4. Use the following code to retrieve the available shipping methods for a specific customer group:**

```
    $customerGroupId = 1; // Replace with the desired customer group ID

    try {
        $group = $this->groupRepository->getById($customerGroupId);
        $rateRequest = $this->rateCollector->createRateRequest();
        $rateRequest->setAllItems([]);
        $rateRequest->setDestCountryId('US'); // Replace with the desired country ID
        $rateRequest->setDestPostcode('12345'); // Replace with the desired postal code
        $rateRequest->setCustomerGroupId($group->getId());

        $shippingMethods = $this->shippingMethodManagement->getList($rateRequest);
        
        foreach ($shippingMethods as $shippingMethod) {
            echo $shippingMethod->getMethodCode(); // Output the shipping method code
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); // Handle any exceptions that occur
    }
```